# How do I capture the enter key in a windows forms combobox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, combobox

How do I capture the enter key in a windows forms combo box when the combobox is active?

I've tried to listen to KeyDown and KeyPress and I've created a subclass and overridden ProcessDialogKey, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

/P

Comment: Do you have AcceptButton defined?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hook up the KeyPress event to a method like this:

```
protected void myCombo_OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed", "Attention");                
    }
}
```

I've tested this in a WinForms application with VS2008 and it works.

If it isn't working for you, please post your code.

Comment: I've already tried it. It does not work. Try it your self and see.
Thats why I posted the question.

Comment: One possible reason would be that some other event handler catches the enter first and stops the rest of the handlers do their job. For example a Menu or the form itself.

Comment: You are right. ...it does work when I isolated the code to make it "postable", so the error must lie somewhere else. I'll try searching with Petros hint.

Thanks guys.

Comment: if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) { }

Comment: there is a property on the form that is called KeyPreview, enable it i guess

Answer (score 25):

In case you define AcceptButton on your form, you cannot listen to Enter key in KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress.

In order to check for that, you need to override ProcessCmdKey on FORM:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if ((this.ActiveControl == myComboBox) && (keyData == Keys.Return)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Combo Enter");
        return true;
    } else {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

In this example that would give you message box if you are on combo box and it works as before for all other controls.

Answer (score 13):

or altertatively you can hook up the KeyDown event:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys k)
{
    if (k == Keys.Enter || k == Keys.Return)
    {
        this.Text = null;
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
   {
      // Do something here...
   } else Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your dialog has a button that's eating the enter key because it's set to be the AcceptButton in the form property.
If that's the case then you solve this like this by unsetting the AcceptButton property when the control gets focus then resetting it back once the control loses focus ( in my code, button1 is the accept button )

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = null;
}

private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = button1;
}

private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
```

I have to admit not liking my own solution as it seems a little hacky to unset/set the AcceptButton property so if anyone has a better solution then I'd be interested

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)  // or Key.Enter or Key.Return
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed", "KeyPress Event");                
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set KeyPreview to true on the form.