# How to stop Enter key from deleting ComboBox.Text (with AutoComplete)?

Tags: c#, .net

**SOLVED:** The issue was DropDownStyle.Simple

Every time I press Enter when typing into folderComboBox it deletes the Text.

It turns out that the problem doesn't occur in a fresh project. It only deletes the text when I use auto completion.

```cs
ComboBox folderComboBox = new ComboBox();

void folderComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

- I do not have a Form.AcceptButton (mentioned as an issue in another post).

Similar Posts:

1. [Autocomplete on Combobox onkeypress event eats up the Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760791/autocomplete-on-combobox-onkeypress-event-eats-up-the-enter-key)
2. [How do I capture the enter key in a windows forms combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226726/how-do-i-capture-the-enter-key-in-a-windows-forms-combobox)

Comment: I use VS 2010 and I tried your code but I can't see your problem.

Comment: I'm running in VS2010 as well. I ran from a fresh project and didn't get the same results. Thanks hamed. Now to see if I can find the issue in the original project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown; //DEFAULT
```

**Issues:**

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.Simple; //MAIN CAUSE OF ISSUE
comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories;
```

Comment: I've changed my DropDownStyle to Simple. Did you accidentally switch them? Simple works for me.

Comment: I doubt it. I seemed to have been annoyed by Simple style. Maybe they changed it in VS2012+.